# Remove focus from listbox options on mouse click only

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility, wcag

I am implementing the following combobox: https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/combobox/examples/combobox-select-only/

As you can notice in the example code from the link above, when I click with my mouse on the combobox, there is a blue focus around the selected option in the listbox.

How do I remove this focus when interacting with the combobox using mouse? I would like to keep the focus when interacting with the combobox using keyboard only.

```js
/*
 *   This content is licensed according to the W3C Software License at
 *   https://www.w3.org/Consortium/Legal/2015/copyright-software-and-document
 */

'use strict';

// Save a list of named combobox actions, for future readability
const SelectActions = {
  Close: 0,
  CloseSelect: 1,
  First: 2,
  Last: 3,
  Next: 4,
  Open: 5,
  PageDown: 6,
  PageUp: 7,
  Previous: 8,
  Select: 9,
  Type: 10,
};

/*
 * Helper functions
 */

// filter an array of options against an input string
// returns an array of options that begin with the filter string, case-independent
function filterOptions(options = [], filter, exclude = []) {
  return options.filter((option) => {
    const matches = option.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) === 0;
    return matches && exclude.indexOf(option) < 0;
  });
}

// map a key press to an action
function getActionFromKey(event, menuOpen) {
  const {
    key,
    altKey,
    ctrlKey,
    metaKey
  } = event;
  const openKeys = ['ArrowDown', 'ArrowUp', 'Enter', ' ']; // all keys that will do the default open action
  // handle opening when closed
  if (!menuOpen && openKeys.includes(key)) {
    return SelectActions.Open;
  }

  // home and end move the selected option when open or closed
  if (key === 'Home') {
    return SelectActions.First;
  }
  if (key === 'End') {
    return SelectActions.Last;
  }

  // handle typing characters when open or closed
  if (
    key === 'Backspace' ||
    key === 'Clear' ||
    (key.length === 1 && key !== ' ' && !altKey && !ctrlKey && !metaKey)
  ) {
    return SelectActions.Type;
  }

  // handle keys when open
  if (menuOpen) {
    if (key === 'ArrowUp' && altKey) {
      return SelectActions.CloseSelect;
    } else if (key === 'ArrowDown' && !altKey) {
      return SelectActions.Next;
    } else if (key === 'ArrowUp') {
      return SelectActions.Previous;
    } else if (key === 'PageUp') {
      return SelectActions.PageUp;
    } else if (key === 'PageDown') {
      return SelectActions.PageDown;
    } else if (key === 'Escape') {
      return SelectActions.Close;
    } else if (key === 'Enter' || key === ' ') {
      return SelectActions.CloseSelect;
    }
  }
}

// return the index of an option from an array of options, based on a search string
// if the filter is multiple iterations of the same letter (e.g "aaa"), then cycle through first-letter matches
function getIndexByLetter(options, filter, startIndex = 0) {
  const orderedOptions = [
    ...options.slice(startIndex),
    ...options.slice(0, startIndex),
  ];
  const firstMatch = filterOptions(orderedOptions, filter)[0];
  const allSameLetter = (array) => array.every((letter) => letter === array[0]);

  // first check if there is an exact match for the typed string
  if (firstMatch) {
    return options.indexOf(firstMatch);
  }

  // if the same letter is being repeated, cycle through first-letter matches
  else if (allSameLetter(filter.split(''))) {
    const matches = filterOptions(orderedOptions, filter[0]);
    return options.indexOf(matches[0]);
  }

  // if no matches, return -1
  else {
    return -1;
  }
}

// get an updated option index after performing an action
function getUpdatedIndex(currentIndex, maxIndex, action) {
  const pageSize = 10; // used for pageup/pagedown

  switch (action) {
    case SelectActions.First:
      return 0;
    case SelectActions.Last:
      return maxIndex;
    case SelectActions.Previous:
      return Math.max(0, currentIndex - 1);
    case SelectActions.Next:
      return Math.min(maxIndex, currentIndex + 1);
    case SelectActions.PageUp:
      return Math.max(0, currentIndex - pageSize);
    case SelectActions.PageDown:
      return Math.min(maxIndex, currentIndex + pageSize);
    default:
      return currentIndex;
  }
}

// check if element is visible in browser view port
function isElementInView(element) {
  var bounding = element.getBoundingClientRect();

  return (
    bounding.top >= 0 &&
    bounding.left >= 0 &&
    bounding.bottom <=
    (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
    bounding.right <=
    (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
  );
}

// check if an element is currently scrollable
function isScrollable(element) {
  return element && element.clientHeight < element.scrollHeight;
}

// ensure a given child element is within the parent's visible scroll area
// if the child is not visible, scroll the parent
function maintainScrollVisibility(activeElement, scrollParent) {
  const {
    offsetHeight,
    offsetTop
  } = activeElement;
  const {
    offsetHeight: parentOffsetHeight,
    scrollTop
  } = scrollParent;

  const isAbove = offsetTop < scrollTop;
  const isBelow = offsetTop + offsetHeight > scrollTop + parentOffsetHeight;

  if (isAbove) {
    scrollParent.scrollTo(0, offsetTop);
  } else if (isBelow) {
    scrollParent.scrollTo(0, offsetTop - parentOffsetHeight + offsetHeight);
  }
}

/*
 * Select Component
 * Accepts a combobox element and an array of string options
 */
const Select = function(el, options = []) {
  // element refs
  this.el = el;
  this.comboEl = el.querySelector('[role=combobox]');
  this.listboxEl = el.querySelector('[role=listbox]');

  // data
  this.idBase = this.comboEl.id || 'combo';
  this.options = options;

  // state
  this.activeIndex = 0;
  this.open = false;
  this.searchString = '';
  this.searchTimeout = null;

  // init
  if (el && this.comboEl && this.listboxEl) {
    this.init();
  }
};

Select.prototype.init = function() {
  // select first option by default
  this.comboEl.innerHTML = this.options[0];

  // add event listeners
  this.comboEl.addEventListener('blur', this.onComboBlur.bind(this));
  this.listboxEl.addEventListener('focusout', this.onComboBlur.bind(this));
  this.comboEl.addEventListener('click', this.onComboClick.bind(this));
  this.comboEl.addEventListener('keydown', this.onComboKeyDown.bind(this));

  // create options
  this.options.map((option, index) => {
    const optionEl = this.createOption(option, index);
    this.listboxEl.appendChild(optionEl);
  });
};

Select.prototype.createOption = function(optionText, index) {
  const optionEl = document.createElement('div');
  optionEl.setAttribute('role', 'option');
  optionEl.id = `${this.idBase}-${index}`;
  optionEl.className =
    index === 0 ? 'combo-option option-current' : 'combo-option';
  optionEl.setAttribute('aria-selected', `${index === 0}`);
  optionEl.innerText = optionText;

  optionEl.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.onOptionClick(index);
  });
  optionEl.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onOptionMouseDown.bind(this));

  return optionEl;
};

Select.prototype.getSearchString = function(char) {
  // reset typing timeout and start new timeout
  // this allows us to make multiple-letter matches, like a native select
  if (typeof this.searchTimeout === 'number') {
    window.clearTimeout(this.searchTimeout);
  }

  this.searchTimeout = window.setTimeout(() => {
    this.searchString = '';
  }, 500);

  // add most recent letter to saved search string
  this.searchString += char;
  return this.searchString;
};

Select.prototype.onComboBlur = function(event) {
  // do nothing if relatedTarget is contained within listboxEl
  if (this.listboxEl.contains(event.relatedTarget)) {
    return;
  }

  // select current option and close
  if (this.open) {
    this.selectOption(this.activeIndex);
    this.updateMenuState(false, false);
  }
};

Select.prototype.onComboClick = function() {
  this.updateMenuState(!this.open, false);
};

Select.prototype.onComboKeyDown = function(event) {
  const {
    key
  } = event;
  const max = this.options.length - 1;

  const action = getActionFromKey(event, this.open);

  switch (action) {
    case SelectActions.Last:
    case SelectActions.First:
      this.updateMenuState(true);
      // intentional fallthrough
    case SelectActions.Next:
    case SelectActions.Previous:
    case SelectActions.PageUp:
    case SelectActions.PageDown:
      event.preventDefault();
      return this.onOptionChange(
        getUpdatedIndex(this.activeIndex, max, action)
      );
    case SelectActions.CloseSelect:
      event.preventDefault();
      this.selectOption(this.activeIndex);
      // intentional fallthrough
    case SelectActions.Close:
      event.preventDefault();
      return this.updateMenuState(false);
    case SelectActions.Type:
      return this.onComboType(key);
    case SelectActions.Open:
      event.preventDefault();
      return this.updateMenuState(true);
  }
};

Select.prototype.onComboType = function(letter) {
  // open the listbox if it is closed
  this.updateMenuState(true);

  // find the index of the first matching option
  const searchString = this.getSearchString(letter);
  const searchIndex = getIndexByLetter(
    this.options,
    searchString,
    this.activeIndex + 1
  );

  // if a match was found, go to it
  if (searchIndex >= 0) {
    this.onOptionChange(searchIndex);
  }
  // if no matches, clear the timeout and search string
  else {
    window.clearTimeout(this.searchTimeout);
    this.searchString = '';
  }
};

Select.prototype.onOptionChange = function(index) {
  // update state
  this.activeIndex = index;

  // update aria-activedescendant
  this.comboEl.setAttribute('aria-activedescendant', `${this.idBase}-${index}`);

  // update active option styles
  const options = this.el.querySelectorAll('[role=option]');
  [...options].forEach((optionEl) => {
    optionEl.classList.remove('option-current');
  });
  options[index].classList.add('option-current');

  // ensure the new option is in view
  if (isScrollable(this.listboxEl)) {
    maintainScrollVisibility(options[index], this.listboxEl);
  }

  // ensure the new option is visible on screen
  // ensure the new option is in view
  if (!isElementInView(options[index])) {
    options[index].scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'nearest'
    });
  }
};

Select.prototype.onOptionClick = function(index) {
  this.onOptionChange(index);
  this.selectOption(index);
  this.updateMenuState(false);
};

Select.prototype.onOptionMouseDown = function() {
  // Clicking an option will cause a blur event,
  // but we don't want to perform the default keyboard blur action
  this.ignoreBlur = true;
};

Select.prototype.selectOption = function(index) {
  // update state
  this.activeIndex = index;

  // update displayed value
  const selected = this.options[index];
  this.comboEl.innerHTML = selected;

  // update aria-selected
  const options = this.el.querySelectorAll('[role=option]');
  [...options].forEach((optionEl) => {
    optionEl.setAttribute('aria-selected', 'false');
  });
  options[index].setAttribute('aria-selected', 'true');
};

Select.prototype.updateMenuState = function(open, callFocus = true) {
  if (this.open === open) {
    return;
  }

  // update state
  this.open = open;

  // update aria-expanded and styles
  this.comboEl.setAttribute('aria-expanded', `${open}`);
  open ? this.el.classList.add('open') : this.el.classList.remove('open');

  // update activedescendant
  const activeID = open ? `${this.idBase}-${this.activeIndex}` : '';
  this.comboEl.setAttribute('aria-activedescendant', activeID);

  if (activeID === '' && !isElementInView(this.comboEl)) {
    this.comboEl.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'nearest'
    });
  }

  // move focus back to the combobox, if needed
  callFocus && this.comboEl.focus();
};

// init select
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  const options = [
    'Choose a Fruit',
    'Apple',
    'Banana',
    'Blueberry',
    'Boysenberry',
    'Cherry',
    'Cranberry',
    'Durian',
    'Eggplant',
    'Fig',
    'Grape',
    'Guava',
    'Huckleberry',
  ];
  const selectEls = document.querySelectorAll('.js-select');

  selectEls.forEach((el) => {
    new Select(el, options);
  });
});
```

```css
.combo *,
.combo *::before,
.combo *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.combo {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  max-width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.combo::after {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0 0 0 / 75%);
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(0 0 0 / 75%);
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 12px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -65%) rotate(45deg);
  width: 12px;
}

.combo-input {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 2px solid rgb(0 0 0 / 75%);
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  min-height: calc(1.4em + 26px);
  padding: 12px 16px 14px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.open .combo-input {
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.combo-input:focus { 
  border-color: #0067b8;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px #0067b8;
  outline: 4px solid transparent;
}

.combo-label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}

.combo-menu {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0 0 0 / 75%);
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  display: none;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.open .combo-menu {
  display: block;
}

.combo-option {
  padding: 10px 12px 12px;
}

.combo-option:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
}

.combo-option.option-current {
  outline: 3px solid #0067b8;
  outline-offset: -3px;
}

.combo-option[aria-selected="true"] {
  padding-right: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.combo-option[aria-selected="true"]::after {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  content: "";
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  width: 8px;
}
```

```html
<label id="combo1-label" class="combo-label">Favorite Fruit</label>
<div class="combo js-select">
  <div aria-controls="listbox1" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-labelledby="combo1-label" id="combo1" class="combo-input" role="combobox" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="combo-menu" role="listbox" id="listbox1" aria-labelledby="combo1-label" tabindex="-1">


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what iorgv said, you should also consider keeping the `:focus` pseudo-class as some older browser versions do not support `:focus-visible`. You can achieve that using the `@support` rule:

```
.outline-on-keyboard:focus-visible {
   outline: 1px solid;
 }

@supports not selector(:focus-visible) {
   .outline-on-keyboard:focus {
   outline: 1px solid;
  }
 }
```

More on that at: [MDN focus-visible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible)

Comment: This is useful. Thank you for mentioning me. It's an open question for why the OP needs to disable the interaction with the mouse. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: @iorgv I guess because it makes sense. Actually, this is why the :focus-visible was presented in the first place. If a user interacts with something on the page with their mouse, then they probably **know** where that thing is located (meaning they can see it clearly), thus they don't need any indicators (like an outline or a border) to tell them where that thing is. The ones who need this are those who use the keyboard to navigate because of any disability. That is mentioned in the same article I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: It makes better sense applying a different style to each platform/condition, but not disabling it entirely. As your cited article says: _This selector is useful to provide a different focus indicator based on the user's input modality (mouse vs. keyboard)._ For what happens with other people with different disabilities? For instance if they can see but can't control their movement properly (or have other incapabilities doing so), how would they know if they clicked properly if there's no visual feedback.

Comment: @iorgv I get your point, but here is the thing .. If you are navigating with the keyboard, you're just browsing, you're not taking any action, thus adding an indicator (like an outline) makes sense as it tells you where you are now. However, when we say 'point with a mouse', we don't mean hovering, instead, we mean clicking on the element, which triggers a particular action (navigating to another route for instance). In this case the user will know if _they have clicked properly_ by seeing the result of clicking on that element.

Comment: @iorgv Regarding your question on how people who can't control their movement deal with that, this is done by providing other visual effects, like adding a border or a box-shadow on **hover**.

Comment: @iorgv  I do not want to show the outline on mouse click because there is already a "checkmark" next to the selected option. And designers think that this checkmark is sufficient and no need to show the outline too. So I was trying to figure out how to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not perfect but
I hope this can help you:
https://codepen.io/eciccarella/pen/wvOrvQW?editors=1111

I just added the class cool-border to both the html and the css

and in the javascript I inserted a control that disables/enables the border on hover
so if you take the focus from the keyboard you can see the border while if you take the focus from the mouse the border is not shown

```
selectEls.forEach((el) => {
  //my edit start here
  //=================================================================
  el.addEventListener(
    "mouseover",
    (e)=>{
      el.querySelector('.combo-input').classList.remove("cool-border");
      if("iid" in el )clearInterval(el.iid);
    }
  );
  el.addEventListener(
    "mouseout",
    (e)=>{
      el.querySelector('.combo-input').classList.add("cool-border");
      el.iid=setTimeout(()=>{el.querySelector('.combo-input').blur();},200);
    }
  );
  //========================================================================
  //and end here

  new Select(el, options);
});
```

Comment: OP: _"How do I remove this focus when interacting with the combobox using mouse? I would like to keep the focus when interacting with the combobox using keyboard only."_ 

I see no difference.

Comment: Thank you, I've upvoted it, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77883020/2817442) solution is closer.

Answer (score 1):

I have copied your snippet and edited with just 1 line.
When a mouse click event (`mousedown`) occurs on an option element, allowing the combobox to lose focus (using [blur() - Element: blur event - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) method) when clicked with the mouse while maintaining focus when changed using the keyboard.

[sandbox link](https://jsfiddle.net/UtmostCreator/j1vLf5z8/)

Using the following line on line 236 of this snipper:

```js
optionEl.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
    // ...
    this.comboEl.blur(); // Add this line to blur the combobox
    // ...
});
```

Where the `comboEl` element is the main interactive element of the combobox, where users can see the selected option and interact with the combobox to open or close the dropdown list of options.

```js
/*
 *   This content is licensed according to the W3C Software License at
 *   https://www.w3.org/Consortium/Legal/2015/copyright-software-and-document
 */

'use strict';

// Save a list of named combobox actions, for future readability
const SelectActions = {
  Close: 0,
  CloseSelect: 1,
  First: 2,
  Last: 3,
  Next: 4,
  Open: 5,
  PageDown: 6,
  PageUp: 7,
  Previous: 8,
  Select: 9,
  Type: 10,
};

/*
 * Helper functions
 */

// filter an array of options against an input string
// returns an array of options that begin with the filter string, case-independent
function filterOptions(options = [], filter, exclude = []) {
  return options.filter((option) => {
    const matches = option.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) === 0;
    return matches && exclude.indexOf(option) < 0;
  });
}

// map a key press to an action
function getActionFromKey(event, menuOpen) {
  const {
    key,
    altKey,
    ctrlKey,
    metaKey
  } = event;
  const openKeys = ['ArrowDown', 'ArrowUp', 'Enter', ' ']; // all keys that will do the default open action
  // handle opening when closed
  if (!menuOpen && openKeys.includes(key)) {
    return SelectActions.Open;
  }

  // home and end move the selected option when open or closed
  if (key === 'Home') {
    return SelectActions.First;
  }
  if (key === 'End') {
    return SelectActions.Last;
  }

  // handle typing characters when open or closed
  if (
    key === 'Backspace' ||
    key === 'Clear' ||
    (key.length === 1 && key !== ' ' && !altKey && !ctrlKey && !metaKey)
  ) {
    return SelectActions.Type;
  }

  // handle keys when open
  if (menuOpen) {
    if (key === 'ArrowUp' && altKey) {
      return SelectActions.CloseSelect;
    } else if (key === 'ArrowDown' && !altKey) {
      return SelectActions.Next;
    } else if (key === 'ArrowUp') {
      return SelectActions.Previous;
    } else if (key === 'PageUp') {
      return SelectActions.PageUp;
    } else if (key === 'PageDown') {
      return SelectActions.PageDown;
    } else if (key === 'Escape') {
      return SelectActions.Close;
    } else if (key === 'Enter' || key === ' ') {
      return SelectActions.CloseSelect;
    }
  }
}

// return the index of an option from an array of options, based on a search string
// if the filter is multiple iterations of the same letter (e.g "aaa"), then cycle through first-letter matches
function getIndexByLetter(options, filter, startIndex = 0) {
  const orderedOptions = [
    ...options.slice(startIndex),
    ...options.slice(0, startIndex),
  ];
  const firstMatch = filterOptions(orderedOptions, filter)[0];
  const allSameLetter = (array) => array.every((letter) => letter === array[0]);

  // first check if there is an exact match for the typed string
  if (firstMatch) {
    return options.indexOf(firstMatch);
  }

  // if the same letter is being repeated, cycle through first-letter matches
  else if (allSameLetter(filter.split(''))) {
    const matches = filterOptions(orderedOptions, filter[0]);
    return options.indexOf(matches[0]);
  }

  // if no matches, return -1
  else {
    return -1;
  }
}

// get an updated option index after performing an action
function getUpdatedIndex(currentIndex, maxIndex, action) {
  const pageSize = 10; // used for pageup/pagedown

  switch (action) {
    case SelectActions.First:
      return 0;
    case SelectActions.Last:
      return maxIndex;
    case SelectActions.Previous:
      return Math.max(0, currentIndex - 1);
    case SelectActions.Next:
      return Math.min(maxIndex, currentIndex + 1);
    case SelectActions.PageUp:
      return Math.max(0, currentIndex - pageSize);
    case SelectActions.PageDown:
      return Math.min(maxIndex, currentIndex + pageSize);
    default:
      return currentIndex;
  }
}

// check if element is visible in browser view port
function isElementInView(element) {
  var bounding = element.getBoundingClientRect();

  return (
    bounding.top >= 0 &&
    bounding.left >= 0 &&
    bounding.bottom <=
    (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
    bounding.right <=
    (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
  );
}

// check if an element is currently scrollable
function isScrollable(element) {
  return element && element.clientHeight < element.scrollHeight;
}

// ensure a given child element is within the parent's visible scroll area
// if the child is not visible, scroll the parent
function maintainScrollVisibility(activeElement, scrollParent) {
  const {
    offsetHeight,
    offsetTop
  } = activeElement;
  const {
    offsetHeight: parentOffsetHeight,
    scrollTop
  } = scrollParent;

  const isAbove = offsetTop < scrollTop;
  const isBelow = offsetTop + offsetHeight > scrollTop + parentOffsetHeight;

  if (isAbove) {
    scrollParent.scrollTo(0, offsetTop);
  } else if (isBelow) {
    scrollParent.scrollTo(0, offsetTop - parentOffsetHeight + offsetHeight);
  }
}

/*
 * Select Component
 * Accepts a combobox element and an array of string options
 */
const Select = function(el, options = []) {
  // element refs
  this.el = el;
  this.comboEl = el.querySelector('[role=combobox]');
  this.listboxEl = el.querySelector('[role=listbox]');

  // data
  this.idBase = this.comboEl.id || 'combo';
  this.options = options;

  // state
  this.activeIndex = 0;
  this.open = false;
  this.searchString = '';
  this.searchTimeout = null;

  // init
  if (el && this.comboEl && this.listboxEl) {
    this.init();
  }
};

Select.prototype.init = function() {
  // select first option by default
  this.comboEl.innerHTML = this.options[0];

  // add event listeners
  this.comboEl.addEventListener('blur', this.onComboBlur.bind(this));
  this.listboxEl.addEventListener('focusout', this.onComboBlur.bind(this));
  this.comboEl.addEventListener('click', this.onComboClick.bind(this));
  this.comboEl.addEventListener('keydown', this.onComboKeyDown.bind(this));

  // create options
  this.options.map((option, index) => {
    const optionEl = this.createOption(option, index);
    this.listboxEl.appendChild(optionEl);
  });
};

Select.prototype.createOption = function(optionText, index) {
  const optionEl = document.createElement('div');
  optionEl.setAttribute('role', 'option');
  optionEl.id = `${this.idBase}-${index}`;
  optionEl.className =
    index === 0 ? 'combo-option option-current' : 'combo-option';
  optionEl.setAttribute('aria-selected', `${index === 0}`);
  optionEl.innerText = optionText;

  optionEl.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.onOptionClick(index);
  });
  optionEl.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.onOptionClick(index);
    this.comboEl.blur(); // Add this line to blur the combobox
  });
  optionEl.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onOptionMouseDown.bind(this));

  return optionEl;
};

Select.prototype.getSearchString = function(char) {
  // reset typing timeout and start new timeout
  // this allows us to make multiple-letter matches, like a native select
  if (typeof this.searchTimeout === 'number') {
    window.clearTimeout(this.searchTimeout);
  }

  this.searchTimeout = window.setTimeout(() => {
    this.searchString = '';
  }, 500);

  // add most recent letter to saved search string
  this.searchString += char;
  return this.searchString;
};

Select.prototype.onComboBlur = function(event) {
  // do nothing if relatedTarget is contained within listboxEl
  if (this.listboxEl.contains(event.relatedTarget)) {
    return;
  }

  // select current option and close
  if (this.open) {
    this.selectOption(this.activeIndex);
    this.updateMenuState(false, false);
  }
};

Select.prototype.onComboClick = function() {
  this.updateMenuState(!this.open, false);
};

Select.prototype.onComboKeyDown = function(event) {
  const {
    key
  } = event;
  const max = this.options.length - 1;

  const action = getActionFromKey(event, this.open);

  switch (action) {
    case SelectActions.Last:
    case SelectActions.First:
      this.updateMenuState(true);
      // intentional fallthrough
    case SelectActions.Next:
    case SelectActions.Previous:
    case SelectActions.PageUp:
    case SelectActions.PageDown:
      event.preventDefault();
      return this.onOptionChange(
        getUpdatedIndex(this.activeIndex, max, action)
      );
    case SelectActions.CloseSelect:
      event.preventDefault();
      this.selectOption(this.activeIndex);
      // intentional fallthrough
    case SelectActions.Close:
      event.preventDefault();
      return this.updateMenuState(false);
    case SelectActions.Type:
      return this.onComboType(key);
    case SelectActions.Open:
      event.preventDefault();
      return this.updateMenuState(true);
  }
};

Select.prototype.onComboType = function(letter) {
  // open the listbox if it is closed
  this.updateMenuState(true);

  // find the index of the first matching option
  const searchString = this.getSearchString(letter);
  const searchIndex = getIndexByLetter(
    this.options,
    searchString,
    this.activeIndex + 1
  );

  // if a match was found, go to it
  if (searchIndex >= 0) {
    this.onOptionChange(searchIndex);
  }
  // if no matches, clear the timeout and search string
  else {
    window.clearTimeout(this.searchTimeout);
    this.searchString = '';
  }
};

Select.prototype.onOptionChange = function(index) {
  // update state
  this.activeIndex = index;

  // update aria-activedescendant
  this.comboEl.setAttribute('aria-activedescendant', `${this.idBase}-${index}`);

  // update active option styles
  const options = this.el.querySelectorAll('[role=option]');
  [...options].forEach((optionEl) => {
    optionEl.classList.remove('option-current');
  });
  options[index].classList.add('option-current');

  // ensure the new option is in view
  if (isScrollable(this.listboxEl)) {
    maintainScrollVisibility(options[index], this.listboxEl);
  }

  // ensure the new option is visible on screen
  // ensure the new option is in view
  if (!isElementInView(options[index])) {
    options[index].scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'nearest'
    });
  }
};

Select.prototype.onOptionClick = function(index) {
  this.onOptionChange(index);
  this.selectOption(index);
  this.updateMenuState(false);
};

Select.prototype.onOptionMouseDown = function() {
  // Clicking an option will cause a blur event,
  // but we don't want to perform the default keyboard blur action
  this.ignoreBlur = true;
};

Select.prototype.selectOption = function(index) {
  // update state
  this.activeIndex = index;

  // update displayed value
  const selected = this.options[index];
  this.comboEl.innerHTML = selected;

  // update aria-selected
  const options = this.el.querySelectorAll('[role=option]');
  [...options].forEach((optionEl) => {
    optionEl.setAttribute('aria-selected', 'false');
  });
  options[index].setAttribute('aria-selected', 'true');
};

Select.prototype.updateMenuState = function(open, callFocus = true) {
  if (this.open === open) {
    return;
  }

  // update state
  this.open = open;

  // update aria-expanded and styles
  this.comboEl.setAttribute('aria-expanded', `${open}`);
  open ? this.el.classList.add('open') : this.el.classList.remove('open');

  // update activedescendant
  const activeID = open ? `${this.idBase}-${this.activeIndex}` : '';
  this.comboEl.setAttribute('aria-activedescendant', activeID);

  if (activeID === '' && !isElementInView(this.comboEl)) {
    this.comboEl.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'nearest'
    });
  }

  // move focus back to the combobox, if needed
  callFocus && this.comboEl.focus();
};

// init select
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  const options = [
    'Choose a Fruit',
    'Apple',
    'Banana',
    'Blueberry',
    'Boysenberry',
    'Cherry',
    'Cranberry',
    'Durian',
    'Eggplant',
    'Fig',
    'Grape',
    'Guava',
    'Huckleberry',
  ];
  const selectEls = document.querySelectorAll('.js-select');

  selectEls.forEach((el) => {
    new Select(el, options);
  });
});
```

```css
.combo *,
.combo *::before,
.combo *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.combo {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  max-width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.combo::after {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0 0 0 / 75%);
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(0 0 0 / 75%);
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 12px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -65%) rotate(45deg);
  width: 12px;
}

.combo-input {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 2px solid rgb(0 0 0 / 75%);
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  min-height: calc(1.4em + 26px);
  padding: 12px 16px 14px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.open .combo-input {
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.combo-input:focus {
  border-color: #0067b8;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px #0067b8;
  outline: 4px solid transparent;
}

.combo-label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}

.combo-menu {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0 0 0 / 75%);
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  display: none;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.open .combo-menu {
  display: block;
}

.combo-option {
  padding: 10px 12px 12px;
}

.combo-option:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
}

.combo-option.option-current {
  outline: 3px solid #0067b8;
  outline-offset: -3px;
}

.combo-option[aria-selected="true"] {
  padding-right: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.combo-option[aria-selected="true"]::after {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  content: "";
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  width: 8px;
}
```

```html
<label id="combo1-label" class="combo-label">Favorite Fruit</label>
<div class="combo js-select">
  <div aria-controls="listbox1" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-labelledby="combo1-label" id="combo1" class="combo-input" role="combobox" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="combo-menu" role="listbox" id="listbox1" aria-labelledby="combo1-label" tabindex="-1">


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP: _"How do I remove this focus when interacting with the combobox using mouse? I would like to keep the focus when interacting with the combobox using keyboard only."_ I see no difference.

Comment: It works on **windows 10 21h2** and browser *chromium v.120.0.6099.234(64bit)* - in my setup it works as you click with a mouse, and stays ok when i use keyboard. Could you please specify your setup (browser OS and its version, please). I suspect this might be the issue; once confirmed, it will be easier to determine the correct way to try to solve it. I have just tested with **Android 14** and the same version of *chromium*

Comment: Do you use IOS or MacOS and safari browser? A blur issue is described in this post: https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web/issues/137#issuecomment-191504574

Comment: I use **Windows 11 Home 22H2**, and the browser is **Edge 121.0.2277.83**. Still... but I'm not the OP, so we'll have to wait for him to react to your work. I'm upvoting for your effort.

Comment: @iorgv, it's a bit strange, but for me in **Edge 120** (which has just updated to **Edge 121**), the focus is removed in my case. I've tested it on both JSFiddle and stackoverflow snippet. I hope this information helps. If you encounter any specific errors or issues, please let me know, and I'll do my best to address them. However, at the moment, I'm a bit puzzled as to why you cannot see the removal of focus

Comment: The "only" difference I see is that the focus after selection is not there on the click event, only when they are selected with keyboard - which I guess is good... I'll check something and get back to you.

Comment: Yes, I only had to complete it with the `:focus-visible`. Thank you. Congrats on your points!

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector `:focus-visible` that is targeting only the elements that were focused via keyboard input.
Info about browser support on [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Afocus-visible).

The `.combo-input:focus` makes the mouse on click focus on the listbox's header only. Changing it to `.combo-input:focus-visible`, will only change that. In order to change how to options behave, we'd need to change the JavaScript, (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77883020/2817442) answer) like so:

```js
/*
 *   This content is licensed according to the W3C Software License at
 *   https://www.w3.org/Consortium/Legal/2015/copyright-software-and-document
 */

'use strict';

// Save a list of named combobox actions, for future readability
const SelectActions = {
  Close: 0,
  CloseSelect: 1,
  First: 2,
  Last: 3,
  Next: 4,
  Open: 5,
  PageDown: 6,
  PageUp: 7,
  Previous: 8,
  Select: 9,
  Type: 10,
};

/*
 * Helper functions
 */

// filter an array of options against an input string
// returns an array of options that begin with the filter string, case-independent
function filterOptions(options = [], filter, exclude = []) {
  return options.filter((option) => {
    const matches = option.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) === 0;
    return matches && exclude.indexOf(option) < 0;
  });
}

// map a key press to an action
function getActionFromKey(event, menuOpen) {
  const {
    key,
    altKey,
    ctrlKey,
    metaKey
  } = event;
  const openKeys = ['ArrowDown', 'ArrowUp', 'Enter', ' ']; // all keys that will do the default open action
  // handle opening when closed
  if (!menuOpen && openKeys.includes(key)) {
    return SelectActions.Open;
  }

  // home and end move the selected option when open or closed
  if (key === 'Home') {
    return SelectActions.First;
  }
  if (key === 'End') {
    return SelectActions.Last;
  }

  // handle typing characters when open or closed
  if (
    key === 'Backspace' ||
    key === 'Clear' ||
    (key.length === 1 && key !== ' ' && !altKey && !ctrlKey && !metaKey)
  ) {
    return SelectActions.Type;
  }

  // handle keys when open
  if (menuOpen) {
    if (key === 'ArrowUp' && altKey) {
      return SelectActions.CloseSelect;
    } else if (key === 'ArrowDown' && !altKey) {
      return SelectActions.Next;
    } else if (key === 'ArrowUp') {
      return SelectActions.Previous;
    } else if (key === 'PageUp') {
      return SelectActions.PageUp;
    } else if (key === 'PageDown') {
      return SelectActions.PageDown;
    } else if (key === 'Escape') {
      return SelectActions.Close;
    } else if (key === 'Enter' || key === ' ') {
      return SelectActions.CloseSelect;
    }
  }
}

// return the index of an option from an array of options, based on a search string
// if the filter is multiple iterations of the same letter (e.g "aaa"), then cycle through first-letter matches
function getIndexByLetter(options, filter, startIndex = 0) {
  const orderedOptions = [
    ...options.slice(startIndex),
    ...options.slice(0, startIndex),
  ];
  const firstMatch = filterOptions(orderedOptions, filter)[0];
  const allSameLetter = (array) => array.every((letter) => letter === array[0]);

  // first check if there is an exact match for the typed string
  if (firstMatch) {
    return options.indexOf(firstMatch);
  }

  // if the same letter is being repeated, cycle through first-letter matches
  else if (allSameLetter(filter.split(''))) {
    const matches = filterOptions(orderedOptions, filter[0]);
    return options.indexOf(matches[0]);
  }

  // if no matches, return -1
  else {
    return -1;
  }
}

// get an updated option index after performing an action
function getUpdatedIndex(currentIndex, maxIndex, action) {
  const pageSize = 10; // used for pageup/pagedown

  switch (action) {
    case SelectActions.First:
      return 0;
    case SelectActions.Last:
      return maxIndex;
    case SelectActions.Previous:
      return Math.max(0, currentIndex - 1);
    case SelectActions.Next:
      return Math.min(maxIndex, currentIndex + 1);
    case SelectActions.PageUp:
      return Math.max(0, currentIndex - pageSize);
    case SelectActions.PageDown:
      return Math.min(maxIndex, currentIndex + pageSize);
    default:
      return currentIndex;
  }
}

// check if element is visible in browser view port
function isElementInView(element) {
  var bounding = element.getBoundingClientRect();

  return (
    bounding.top >= 0 &&
    bounding.left >= 0 &&
    bounding.bottom <=
    (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
    bounding.right <=
    (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
  );
}

// check if an element is currently scrollable
function isScrollable(element) {
  return element && element.clientHeight < element.scrollHeight;
}

// ensure a given child element is within the parent's visible scroll area
// if the child is not visible, scroll the parent
function maintainScrollVisibility(activeElement, scrollParent) {
  const {
    offsetHeight,
    offsetTop
  } = activeElement;
  const {
    offsetHeight: parentOffsetHeight,
    scrollTop
  } = scrollParent;

  const isAbove = offsetTop < scrollTop;
  const isBelow = offsetTop + offsetHeight > scrollTop + parentOffsetHeight;

  if (isAbove) {
    scrollParent.scrollTo(0, offsetTop);
  } else if (isBelow) {
    scrollParent.scrollTo(0, offsetTop - parentOffsetHeight + offsetHeight);
  }
}

/*
 * Select Component
 * Accepts a combobox element and an array of string options
 */
const Select = function(el, options = []) {
  // element refs
  this.el = el;
  this.comboEl = el.querySelector('[role=combobox]');
  this.listboxEl = el.querySelector('[role=listbox]');

  // data
  this.idBase = this.comboEl.id || 'combo';
  this.options = options;

  // state
  this.activeIndex = 0;
  this.open = false;
  this.searchString = '';
  this.searchTimeout = null;

  // init
  if (el && this.comboEl && this.listboxEl) {
    this.init();
  }
};

Select.prototype.init = function() {
  // select first option by default
  this.comboEl.innerHTML = this.options[0];

  // add event listeners
  this.comboEl.addEventListener('blur', this.onComboBlur.bind(this));
  this.listboxEl.addEventListener('focusout', this.onComboBlur.bind(this));
  this.comboEl.addEventListener('click', this.onComboClick.bind(this));
  this.comboEl.addEventListener('keydown', this.onComboKeyDown.bind(this));

  // create options
  this.options.map((option, index) => {
    const optionEl = this.createOption(option, index);
    this.listboxEl.appendChild(optionEl);
  });
};

Select.prototype.createOption = function(optionText, index) {
  const optionEl = document.createElement('div');
  optionEl.setAttribute('role', 'option');
  optionEl.id = `${this.idBase}-${index}`;
  optionEl.className =
    index === 0 ? 'combo-option option-current' : 'combo-option';
  optionEl.setAttribute('aria-selected', `${index === 0}`);
  optionEl.innerText = optionText;

  optionEl.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.onOptionClick(index);
  });
  optionEl.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.onOptionClick(index);
    this.comboEl.blur(); // Add this line to blur the combobox
  });
  optionEl.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onOptionMouseDown.bind(this));

  return optionEl;
};

Select.prototype.getSearchString = function(char) {
  // reset typing timeout and start new timeout
  // this allows us to make multiple-letter matches, like a native select
  if (typeof this.searchTimeout === 'number') {
    window.clearTimeout(this.searchTimeout);
  }

  this.searchTimeout = window.setTimeout(() => {
    this.searchString = '';
  }, 500);

  // add most recent letter to saved search string
  this.searchString += char;
  return this.searchString;
};

Select.prototype.onComboBlur = function(event) {
  // do nothing if relatedTarget is contained within listboxEl
  if (this.listboxEl.contains(event.relatedTarget)) {
    return;
  }

  // select current option and close
  if (this.open) {
    this.selectOption(this.activeIndex);
    this.updateMenuState(false, false);
  }
};

Select.prototype.onComboClick = function() {
  this.updateMenuState(!this.open, false);
};

Select.prototype.onComboKeyDown = function(event) {
  const {
    key
  } = event;
  const max = this.options.length - 1;

  const action = getActionFromKey(event, this.open);

  switch (action) {
    case SelectActions.Last:
    case SelectActions.First:
      this.updateMenuState(true);
      // intentional fallthrough
    case SelectActions.Next:
    case SelectActions.Previous:
    case SelectActions.PageUp:
    case SelectActions.PageDown:
      event.preventDefault();
      return this.onOptionChange(
        getUpdatedIndex(this.activeIndex, max, action)
      );
    case SelectActions.CloseSelect:
      event.preventDefault();
      this.selectOption(this.activeIndex);
      // intentional fallthrough
    case SelectActions.Close:
      event.preventDefault();
      return this.updateMenuState(false);
    case SelectActions.Type:
      return this.onComboType(key);
    case SelectActions.Open:
      event.preventDefault();
      return this.updateMenuState(true);
  }
};

Select.prototype.onComboType = function(letter) {
  // open the listbox if it is closed
  this.updateMenuState(true);

  // find the index of the first matching option
  const searchString = this.getSearchString(letter);
  const searchIndex = getIndexByLetter(
    this.options,
    searchString,
    this.activeIndex + 1
  );

  // if a match was found, go to it
  if (searchIndex >= 0) {
    this.onOptionChange(searchIndex);
  }
  // if no matches, clear the timeout and search string
  else {
    window.clearTimeout(this.searchTimeout);
    this.searchString = '';
  }
};

Select.prototype.onOptionChange = function(index) {
  // update state
  this.activeIndex = index;

  // update aria-activedescendant
  this.comboEl.setAttribute('aria-activedescendant', `${this.idBase}-${index}`);

  // update active option styles
  const options = this.el.querySelectorAll('[role=option]');
  [...options].forEach((optionEl) => {
    optionEl.classList.remove('option-current');
  });
  options[index].classList.add('option-current');

  // ensure the new option is in view
  if (isScrollable(this.listboxEl)) {
    maintainScrollVisibility(options[index], this.listboxEl);
  }

  // ensure the new option is visible on screen
  // ensure the new option is in view
  if (!isElementInView(options[index])) {
    options[index].scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'nearest'
    });
  }
};

Select.prototype.onOptionClick = function(index) {
  this.onOptionChange(index);
  this.selectOption(index);
  this.updateMenuState(false);
};

Select.prototype.onOptionMouseDown = function() {
  // Clicking an option will cause a blur event,
  // but we don't want to perform the default keyboard blur action
  this.ignoreBlur = true;
};

Select.prototype.selectOption = function(index) {
  // update state
  this.activeIndex = index;

  // update displayed value
  const selected = this.options[index];
  this.comboEl.innerHTML = selected;

  // update aria-selected
  const options = this.el.querySelectorAll('[role=option]');
  [...options].forEach((optionEl) => {
    optionEl.setAttribute('aria-selected', 'false');
  });
  options[index].setAttribute('aria-selected', 'true');
};

Select.prototype.updateMenuState = function(open, callFocus = true) {
  if (this.open === open) {
    return;
  }

  // update state
  this.open = open;

  // update aria-expanded and styles
  this.comboEl.setAttribute('aria-expanded', `${open}`);
  open ? this.el.classList.add('open') : this.el.classList.remove('open');

  // update activedescendant
  const activeID = open ? `${this.idBase}-${this.activeIndex}` : '';
  this.comboEl.setAttribute('aria-activedescendant', activeID);

  if (activeID === '' && !isElementInView(this.comboEl)) {
    this.comboEl.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'nearest'
    });
  }

  // move focus back to the combobox, if needed
  callFocus && this.comboEl.focus();
};

// init select
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  const options = [
    'Choose a Fruit',
    'Apple',
    'Banana',
    'Blueberry',
    'Boysenberry',
    'Cherry',
    'Cranberry',
    'Durian',
    'Eggplant',
    'Fig',
    'Grape',
    'Guava',
    'Huckleberry',
  ];
  const selectEls = document.querySelectorAll('.js-select');

  selectEls.forEach((el) => {
    new Select(el, options);
  });
});
```

```css
.combo *,
.combo *::before,
.combo *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.combo {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  max-width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.combo::after {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0 0 0 / 75%);
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(0 0 0 / 75%);
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 12px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -65%) rotate(45deg);
  width: 12px;
}

.combo-input {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 2px solid rgb(0 0 0 / 75%);
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  min-height: calc(1.4em + 26px);
  padding: 12px 16px 14px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.open .combo-input {
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.combo-input:focus-visible { /*NECESSARY MODIFCATION*/
  border-color: #0067b8;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px #0067b8;
  outline: 4px solid transparent;
}

.combo-label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}

.combo-menu {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0 0 0 / 75%);
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  display: none;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.open .combo-menu {
  display: block;
}

.combo-option {
  padding: 10px 12px 12px;
}

.combo-option:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
}

.combo-option.option-current {
  outline: 3px solid #0067b8;
  outline-offset: -3px;
}

.combo-option[aria-selected="true"] {
  padding-right: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.combo-option[aria-selected="true"]::after {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  content: "";
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  width: 8px;
}
```

```html
<label id="combo1-label" class="combo-label">Favorite Fruit</label>
<div class="combo js-select">
  <div aria-controls="listbox1" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-labelledby="combo1-label" id="combo1" class="combo-input" role="combobox" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="combo-menu" role="listbox" id="listbox1" aria-labelledby="combo1-label" tabindex="-1">


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I really appreciate it. This makes sense, However, I do not seem to be able to apply this to the example above. The example above is not using ".combo-input:focus", it is using:

".combo-option.option-current {
    outline: 3px solid #0067b8;
    outline-offset: -3px;
}"

So I am not very sure how to apply your resolution. I tried adding ":focus-visible" at the end of the style: ".combo-option.option-current:focus-visible {
    outline: 3px solid #0067b8;
    outline-offset: -3px;
}", but that did not work. Any idea? Thank you so much

Comment: This is out of the scope of my followed and know tags. Edit the question to add JavaScript as tag in it - and someone might answer your question who's good in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you very much @iorgv for all your help. Unfortunately, I still could not find a resolution for this. The code snippet you provded still shows an outline on mouse click, but I appreciate all the help. If I resolved this I will post the resolution here.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Is this what you want?

Comment: In your updated answer, the focus is now completely removed even for keyboard interaction. I wanted to keep the focus for keyboard interaction but remove it for mouse interaction. Keyboard focus is important to comply with accessibility standards. I really appreciate your efforts in trying to resolve this!

Comment: @zara I've updated my answer. Please, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

What if you just highlight the drop down menus on mouse hover and keyboard interaction.

Remove these rules:

```
.combo-option:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
}

.combo-option.option-current {
  outline: 3px solid #0067b8;
  outline-offset: -3px;
}
```

and add this:

```
.combo-option.option-current,
.combo-option:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 10%); // Whatever background color you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **:focus-visible** pseudo-class instead of the **:focus** pseudo-class on the .combo-input element.

Here's the modified CSS for the **.combo-input** element:

```
.combo-input:focus-visible {
  border-color: #0067b8;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px #0067b8;
  outline: 4px solid transparent;
}

.combo-input:focus:not(:focus-visible) {
  outline: none;
}
```